# How to check for falsy values in properties of a chain of connected objects?

Tags: javascript

I'm using the [Logical OR (||) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) to check and assign values if they are not falsy in the following way:

```
let locationDistrict =
                    result.results[0].address_components[2].long_name ||
                    result.results[0].address_components[1].long_name ||
                    result.results[0].address_components[0].long_name ||
                    'unknown district';
```

But when `result`, `result.results`, `result.results[0]` or `address_components` is undefined, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property [name_of_property] of undefined
```

I tried fixing this using the [Optional chaining (?.) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to access properties, as below:

```
let locationDistrict =
                    result?.results[0]?.address_components[2]?.long_name ||
                    result?.results[0]?.address_components[1]?.long_name ||
                    result?.results[0]?.address_components[0]?.long_name ||
                    'unknown district';
```

But it still fails without getting to assigning the default value 'unknown district'.

I could get the code to work by using the [Conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and checking for falsy values as below:

```
let locationDistrict =
                    (result && result.results && result.results[0] && result.results[0].address_components[2]) ? result.results[0].address_components[2].long_name :
                    (result && result.results && result.results[0] && result.results[0].address_components[1]) ? result.results[0].address_components[1].long_name :
                    (result && result.results && result.results[0] && result.results[0].address_components[0]) ? result.results[0].address_components[0].long_name :
                    'unknown district';
```

But I'm sure there's a better and more legant way to do this.

Why isn't the `||` operator picking up the 'undefined' value of the expression when either of it's chained objects is undefined? How should I use the `||` operator  to check for falsy values when the left-hand side operand contains deeply located properties within a chain of connected objects?

Comment: You need `?.` before the `[0]` also. Oh and the `address_components` indexes.

Comment: A better way is combining storing result of `_.get(result, 'results[0].address_components')` in some temp variable, then proceeding with accessing its `[0], [1], [2], ...` properties. Still, it's not really clear why do you even have to deal with such convoluted data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is this what you are looking for ?

```js
let result = {};

let locationDistrict =
                    result?.results?.[0]?.address_components?.[2].long_name ||
                    result?.results?.[0]?.address_components?.[1].long_name ||
                    result?.results?.[0]?.address_components?.[0].long_name ||
                    'unknown district';

console.log(locationDistrict)
```

Comment: You should probably mention that this not supported in older browsers (most versions since early 2020): https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining

The default way before was to indeed use the "logical or" operator.